# Stop a loop after a certain amount of iterations, instead of when a max value is met

Tags: java, loops

JAVA:

I want a for loop that doesnt stop when i is a certain number, but rather after x iterations. Is there any way to do that?

```
public static int seven_sum(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 7; i <= WHAT GOES HERE; i = i * 10 + i) { 
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

Comment: Just make another counter and use that in the condition. Nothing says you have to use `i` in the condition (even though it is the same thing).

Comment: I is a certain number after a number of iterations...

Comment: What is a difference between 'when i is certain number' and 'x iterations'?

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: if(someCondition) break; ?

Comment: A loop like `for (i=0; i < x; i++)` stops exactly after x iterations, unless you have a `break` statement inside it. What is it that bothers you about this loop? Why do you need something different?

Comment: In a for loop you increment the "i" typically one time for each loop.  So if you are using i++ for example, the loop stops at that number which is the same as the number of iterations of the loop.  It would only be different if you use something like i+=2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare multiple variables of the same type in a for-loop:

```java
public static int seven_sum(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 7, iterations = 0; iterations < (number of iterations); i = i * 10 + i, iterations++) { 
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a certain value summing up in your loop and you want to stop the loop if the value exceeds a certain border. You can just add an `if` statement that checks the value:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // some value to hold a sum
    int valueSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        // in every iteration step, add the current value of i to valueSum
        valueSum += i;

        // print the current values of i and valueSum
        System.out.println("Iteration no " + i + ", value sum = " + valueSum);

        // stop looping if valueSum becomes 500 or greater
        if (valueSum >= 500) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Please check the console output to get a better understanding of `for` loops and iteration in general.

Answer (score 1):

The only case i can think of is: if `x` (number of iterations) is greater than `i` (your index which may depend on some input values like array length etc.) If that is the case you can combine an infinite loop with a break statement:

```
    int iterations = 0;
    for(int i = 0; true ; i++){
        System.out.println("iterations count = " + ++iterations);
        if(iterations == 10) break;
    }
```

or even without declaring an index:

```
    int iterations = 0;
    for( ; ; ){
        System.out.println("iterations count = " + ++iterations);
        if(iterations == 10) break;
    }
```

or if you need two or more independent variables

```
    int x = 10; //number of iterations wanted
    for(int i = 7, j = 0; j<= x; i = i * 10 + i , j++){
        // do something
    }
```